# Target element with target which isn't a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I target a link with _BLANK target but which doesn't have specific class?

```
a[target="_BLANK"] {
   // Do something if this link isn't .skip-this class
}
```

Comment: `a[target="_blank"]:not(".skip-this")` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the CSS [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector

**CSS**

```
a[target="_BLANK"]:not(.skip-this) {
   color: red;
}
```

---

```css
a[target="_BLANK"]:not(.skip-this) {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" target="_BLANK" class="skip-this">Hello</a>
<a href="" target="_BLANK">Hello</a>
```